# Insert into Access DB (loop)

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have this code and its coming up with an INSERT INTO statement error...

Its probably something but I have been at it for a while... please help.

```
'Add items to db'
Function recordOrder()

    objDT = Session("Cart")

    Dim intCounter As Integer


    For intCounter = 0 To objDT.Rows.Count - 1

        objDR = objDT.Rows(intCounter)

        Dim con2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

        Dim myPath2 As String
        myPath2 = Server.MapPath("faraxday.mdb")

        con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=" & myPath2 & ";"
        Dim myCommand2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand

        myCommand2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order(order_date, coupon_id, customer_id, quantity) values('" & System.DateTime.Now & "','" & Int32.Parse(objDR("ID")) & "','" & Int32.Parse(custID) & "','" & Int32.Parse(objDR("quantity")) &"')"
        myCommand2.Connection = con2
        con2.Open()
        myCommand2.ExecuteReader()
        con2.Close()




        test.Text += "Order ID: " & objDR("ID") & "Order Date: " & System.DateTime.Now & ", Cust ID: " & custID & ", Quantity: " & objDR("quantity") &" "

    Next


End Function
```

Comment: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statemen

Comment: you should open and close connection outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting an error by not enclosing the Date inside Pound signs. You have to do this in Jet (Access) when using variables not parameters.

VALUES('#" & DateTime.Now.Date & "#',...

I also took the liberty of refactoring this code for you since you are creating a new connection for each record which is bad news. Use a Try Catch Finally block and move all that stuff outside the For Loop (please see below)

```
    Function recordOrder()

    objDT = Session("Cart")
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim con2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim myPath2 As String
    myPath2 = Server.MapPath("faraxday.mdb")
    con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" <-- etc
    Dim myCommand2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    myCommand2.Connection = con2
    con2.Open()
    Try
        For intCounter = 0 To obDT.Rows.Count - 1
            objDR = objDT.Rows(intCounter)
            myCommand2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order(order_date,coupon_id,customer_id,quantity)" _
                & "VALUES ('#" & System.DateTime.Now.Date & "#','" & Int32.Parse(objDR("ID")) & "','" & Int32.Parse(custID) _
                & "','" & Int32.Parse(objDR("quantity")) & "')"
            myCommand2.ExecuteReader()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle errors here
    Finally
        If con2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con2.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Remember to mark as answered if this helps.

Comment: the values are still not getting stored in the database. im not sure what this problem could be. the query string is correct...

Comment: What's the primary key on the table? If you put a breakpoint in the Catch block do any exceptions popup? What are they?

Comment: there is a primary key but its auto increment so I left it blank. it doesnt display any errors but its not inserting in the db.

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehav

Comment: Assuming you have valid values for everything, change the command from ExecuteQuery to ExecuteNonQuery(). If that doesn't work, try setting the CommandType to CommandType.Text. If all that still doesn't work, finda  way to get a string copy of your insert statement exactly and put it up.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it out by removing the single quotes. Thanks everybody to contributed to this.